# What is the best way to synchronize my local mysql Database with online mysql Database

Tags: c#, mysql

What is the best way to synchronize my local mysql Database with online mysql Database using C# (Any Other solution except creating mysql Dump locally and than restore it on online mysql server).

Comment: You can look at MySQL replication

Comment: Why don't you use an Online MySQL database instead of keeping the data locally ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FEDERATED Storage Engine locally.
Not saying it is the best but it is easy to setup. 
If your MySQL server version is already compiled with federated engine support what MySQL Windows versions seams to have.

> The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL
>   database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a
>   local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote
>   (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables.

source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

But you need to check if your MySQL version supports it and FEDERATED storage engine is actived.

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

Only think is need to make a table copy from every table and make it  FEDERATED  storage engine. 
Best is to make a separated database for it.

Here is a create table example.

```
CREATE TABLE `T1`(`A` VARCHAR(100),UNIQUE KEY(`A`(30)))
ENGINE=FEDERATED
       CONNECTION='MYSQL://127.0.0.1:3306/TEST/T1';
```

Then you can insert, update and delete from that table

Comment: Does remote MySQL server also needs to use Federated storage engine ?

Comment: Well it's not enabled on all servers @MadhurBhaiya the thing is you need to compile it your self if it not in your server... Because FEDERATED table engine more looks a MySQL client i assume the remote MySQL server does not need to have Federated active.

Comment: Suppose I create a  FEDERATED storage engine (copy all my data from previous tables to new Federated engine Tables). But will it effects mysql procedures and other inline queries that are used in Accounts Software (made in C# winform)?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Actually I am thinking that this could be a nice solution to enable my developers to work on Staging (sandbox) database on their local machines - if federated to sandbox. This way they can pretty much simulate production-like conditions

Comment: @SaadAhmad it is hard to explain.. But because you have a "remote" database your current procedures and other queries will not be effected.. One thing is getting the data from the "local" database into the "remote" database so the data will be really on the remote MYSQL server.. That you can do with `INSERT INTO remote.table SELECT * FROM local.table WHERE local.table.id = <value>` in the C# for every data point.. Or you create triggers in MySQL to do the copy (best method).

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Thanks alot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use MySQL Replication feature.

> Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master) to be copied to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves). Replication is asynchronous by default; slaves do not need to be connected permanently to receive updates from the master. Depending on the configuration, you can replicate all databases, selected databases, or even selected tables within a database.

You can find more information at the [MySQL official website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html)